# Naive questions on 1-cocycles of loally compact groups.

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis, representation-theory, group-cohomology, locally-compact-groups

Let $\pi$ be an orthogonal representation of locally compact group $G$ on a real Hilbert space $H$. Recall that a continuous mapping $b \colon G \to H$ such that $b(gh) = b(g) + π(g)b(h)$, for all $g, h \in G$ is called a 1-cocycle with respect to $\pi$.

1) Suppose that $G$ is second countable. Is it possible to reduce the study of 1-cocycles to the study of 1-cocycles with a *separable* Hilbert space ?

2) Why the use of *real* Hilbert spaces is  important (essential ?) in the theory ?

Comment: "To reduce" is too vague to have a sensible answer to (1). For instance, $G$ second countable usually has uncountably many irreducible representations, so a representation containing all irreducibles has to be non-separable... Still irreducible, and more generally cyclic representations are separable, and representations with a cyclic vector are well-encoded in the notion of positive definite function (see appendix of the Bekka-Harpe-Valette book). (2) No, complex Hilbert spaces work well, with unitary representations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

Comment: 1) OK I had little hope 2) In the Bekka-Harpe-Valettebook, the authors only use real cocycle in chapter "property" FH. The reasons are unclear.